# How to find a document in MongoDB, update it, and insert a new document?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

What would be the correct command to find a document in a MongoDB database, update it and then insert the updated document as a new document with a new _id?
The original document should remain completely unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mongoose, MongoDB shell or Compass?
If you want to find a document and update it, why do you need a new id? 
If you want to update an existing document, the id will remain the same, or you can a find and copy an existing document to a new one and update the new doc.

Comment: Actually, I am working with python using pymongo. Obviously, I can find a document, change it using python and then insert the new one. But I am wondering if there is a built-in command in MongoDB for that.

Comment: Im not tooo fimiliar with the python commands.  Using mongodb directly, you can use "findOneAndUpdate".
This link has some nice examples and explanations:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/. 
or you can also use:  "findOneAndReplace":  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/
Hope I understood your question correctly

Comment: I think both these functions change the existing document. I am interested in keeping the existing document completely unchanged and inserting a new document.